# What am I missing in my firestore security rules that It denies every read and write?

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I am using firebase rules simulator, but It denies read, write for authenticated or non-authenticated users.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/collection1/{document=**} {
    allow read: if true;
    allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
  }
  match /databases/collection2/{document=**} {
    allow read: if false;
    allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
    allow update, delete: if false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rules should start like this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
```

Your rules are missing the `/databases/{database}` part so they are not matching to anything and denying everything. You can re-write your example like so:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Matches every document in collection1 and every subcollection under it
    match /collection1/{document=**} {
       allow read;
       allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
   // Matches every document in collection2 and every subcollection under it
    match /collection2/{document=**} {
       allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

This allowed the following simulated requests:

- `get unauthenticated /collection1/doc1`
- `create authenticated /collection1/doc2`
- `create authenticated /collection2/doc3`

[image: example successful request]

Other simulated requests are denied as expected.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Simulated read/write denied, It denies each and every read and write even after I replace my security rules with the ones you wrote.

Comment: In the nested match statement If i remove '/collection1', It works as desired. but I want to be able to set custom rules for individual collections. idk, what's wrong.

Comment: Updated rules to simplify and added some example simulated requests. You should be able to set up rules for individual collection like this. Can you add some example requests to your question?

Comment: Thank you so much, Juan! I was really struggling on this, once again thanks.